# Rails Multi Level has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I am trying to build the multi-level model as demonstrated. When a user creates a campaign they will select some categories and some metros from tables Category and Metro. Those selections will then be placed within two tables as campaign_category and campaign_metro. But upon the creation of those entries I wish for then another table to be populated with the permutation of those combinations within table campaign_category_metro to allow for linking the campaign, the category and metros selected for a user to set a bid price on.

**UPDATED:**

For example say a user creates a campaign that has id 10 and selects category with id 1 and 2, and metros with id 3 and 4. In the tables campaign_category appears:

[image]

and in table campaign_metro appears:

[image]

In campagin_category_metro I want to have those permuted rows from the tables above as:

[image]

Then a user can set a bid on those campaign/metro combinations.

As of now, in creating a campaign, and selecting categories and metros I can get the tables campaign_category and campaign_metro populated but the final table, campaign_category_metro, remains blank. Below is my model as is:

First Level:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base   
    has_many :campaign_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :metros, through: :campaign_metros

    has_many :campaign_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, through: :campaign_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaign_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaigns, through: :campaign_categories
end

class Metro < ActiveRecord::Base   
    has_many :campaign_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaigns, through: :campaign_metros
end
```

Second Level (populates, but the relation to campaign_category_metro does nothing):

```
class CampaignCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
    belongs_to :category

    has_many :campaign_category_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaign_metros, through: :campaign_category_metros
end

class CampaignMetro < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
    belongs_to :metro

    has_many :campaign_category_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaign_categories, through: :campaign_category_metros
end
```

Third Level (Nothing shows up upon creation of a campaign):

```
class CampaignCategoryMetro < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign_category
    belongs_to :campaign_metro
end
```

How can I allow for the third level table to be populated with the total permutations of selected category and metro upon the creation of a campaign?

Comment: What are you trying to solve with CampaignCategoryMetro?  The information in it would be redundant even if it were populated.

Comment: Yea, why does you join model need a record to know what the other model is? You can just ask its parent that.

Comment: I have updated the table campaign_category_metro to demonstrate why. Each selection for category and metro, the combinations of such groupings will have their own respective bid price that the user sets later

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Is there any addition that can be made so that the  table campaign_category_metro is populated upon creation of a Campaign and selection of Categories and Metros?

Comment: What's the purpose of the campaign_category_metro table? Your question is unclear. I'm confused with your schema. You're trying to get alt the combinations of pairs metro and category that have been selected for every campaign created?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Yes, when a user creates a campaign that has id 10 and selects category with id 1 and 2, and metros with id 3 and 4. In the tables campaign_category appears a row for (10, 1) with id 15 and (10, 2) with id 16 and in table campaign_metro appears a row for (10, 3) with id 25 and (10, 4) with id 26. In campagin_category_metro I want to have those permuted rows from the above tables (with id from campaign_category first) as (15,25)(15,26)(16,25)(16,26), then a user can set a bid on those campaign/metro combinations ie a bid for (15,25) will be for the set of category 1 and metro 3

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I updated the question with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will result in the campaign_category_metro table you posted in your example:

```
campaign = Campaign.create # pretend the id is now 10

# this will create the join tables you provided as examples
campaign.categories << [Category.find(1), Category.find(2)]
campaign.metros << [Metro.find(3), Metro.find(4)]

# Get the join tables
campaign_categories = campaign.campaign_categories
campaign_metros = campaign.campaign_metros
```

We now have these:

[image: campaign_categories]
[image: campaign_metros]

So far so good, just setting some context to make sure we're on the same page. Now to generate the final permutation and create that last table:

```
@campaign_category_metros = []

# this outer loop will run twice and provide campaign_category ids 15 and 16
campaign_categories.each do |campaign_category|
  # this inner loop will run twice and provide campaign_metro ids 25 and 26
  campaign_metros.each do |campaign_metro|
    # this next bit will run 4 times and pair 15 with 25 and 26 and 16 with 25 and 26
    @campaign_category_metros << CampaignCategoryMetro.create({
      campaign_category_id: campaign_category.id,
      campaign_metro_id: campaign_metro.id
    })
  end
end
```

Now `@campaign_category_metros` will be equal to:

[image: campaign_category_metro]

except with blank bids of course. You can render `@campaign_category_metros` in a list to allow users to bid on those 4 combinations.

The idea here is that with each `campaign_category` we'll create a `campaign_category_metro` record with each `campaign_metro`.

**Note:** There isn't a built mechanism in Rails that will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks. Note: I use active record for the creation of campaign_category and campaign_metro. But for your implementation, how updatable is the campaign_category_metro table if we simply hard code the creation of the records as you outlined. Or do I need to also build the separate update/edit methods as well and just watch out for changes in the model?

Comment: You'd put that code in or call it from the campaign controllers create actin since you want to create new permutations as new campaigns are made. Then in a campaign_category_metros controller you can update those final records directly.

Comment: Also note that the first code snippet I wrote where I create the `campaign.categories` and `campaign.metros` is just an example that represents what you already do in your views to have the user create a campaign and select the categories and metros. Don't use that part, just the part where you use the current created campaign's metros and categories to create the final table.

Comment: ok, If I also edit/update those original selections of metro and category for the campaign, as in I will no longer be using the category 15 or 16, and switch to category 82 and 12, how can I then delete those other rows in Campaign_Category_Metro?

Comment: In that case I'd add a `campaign_id` field to the `campaign_category_metros` table to keep track of which campaign created those permutations and when you delete a campaign just call `CampaignCategoryMetro.where(campaign_id: @campaign_id).delete_all`. Make sure to add the campaign_id when you're creating the permutations in the nested loop code I gave.

Comment: In the case of an update where you change a selection, the quick and dirty way would be to delete all permutation by that campaign first as explained in my previous comment, and then generate them all again as before.

Comment: That leads to data duplication. i am starting to think my model layout is not going to work for the application. Is there a better relation for tables than what I am trying? Or some point of reference for advanced data models?

Comment: I got the final table populated successfully!! But how can I have the records deleted upon the removal of those related records in the tables `campaign_category` and `campaign_metro`?